# How do Beamer's approaches for skipping labeled and unlabeled slides differ?

Tags: beamer, macros, performance

I am trying to understand an issue in Beamer that substantially reduces efficiency of using `\includeonlyframes` for the purpose of improving compilation times: whenever the slide lacks a label, it seems to undergo typesetting, even if its overlay specification is `<all:0>` or `\includeonlyframes` is active. On the contrary, if there is a label, the slide is discarded in an efficient manner.

Quoting my MWE from the [corresponding issue in the Beamer repo on Github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/866):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<all:0>[label=SkipMe]
        1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<all:0>
        2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above produces one `overfull hbox` warning, when typesetting the second (unlabeled) slide. The first slide is not typeset at all.

Looking at `base/beamerbaseframe.sty`, I can (painstakingly) trace the difference to the use of `\beamer@donoframe` in the unlabeled (slow) case, vs. `\beamer@doseveralframes` in the labeled (fast) case. Their implementation strategies seem quite different, and I wonder if `donoframe` could adopt a faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

well you could probably add a default label to every frame (I'm highjacking the environment key as it is just before the general keys are set):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{myframecount}
\define@key{beamerframe}{environment}
 {%
  \stepcounter{myframecount}%
  \edef\beamer@againname{\themyframecount}%
{\let\@elt\beamer@labelsavecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
  \def\beamer@frameenvironmentsubst{#1}%
 }
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<all:0>[label=bad]
        1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<all:0>
        2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails to compile when `<all:0>` overlay specifications are removed.

Comment: ah right. I added an edit. But I'm not completly sure that it doesn't fall over somewhere.

Comment: Your answer is pristine, did your edit not reach the server somehow?

Comment: sorry got distracted. Perhaps one will need some additional code from the relabel key, but this is all not really documentated ...

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, while this works for the MWE, it fails on a complex document.

Comment: Since this does not answer the stated question, but only suggests a workaround, I'm afraid I have to downvote it to avoid automatic bounty assignment.